# How to add search icon to TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

Is it possible to display hint in the `TextField` as in the image below?

[image: search field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no proper way to add icon in hint, but you can try this alternative, use rich text on textfield as hint text, hide when tap on textfield and show with condition when textfield is empty and keyboard is hide:

```
            Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              children: [
                Offstage(
                  offstage: _isHide,
                  child: IgnorePointer(
                    ignoring: true,
                    child: Text.rich(
                      TextSpan(
                        children: [
                          WidgetSpan(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "blablablablabla",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(onTap: () {
                  _isHide = true;
                  setState(() {});
                }),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. Used [**`prefixIcon`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/prefixIcon.html) for that.

```
   TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          hintText: 'Search Tech Talk',
        ),
      ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: I tried `prefixIcon`. But the problem is that both the icon and the hint should look in the `Center`.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `Prefix icon` property and content padding in the textfield widget

Answer (score 0):

```
            TextField(
                onChanged: (value){
               searchData(st = value.trim().toLowerCase());
                 // Method For Searching 
                           },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search Data",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                     borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

***RESULT***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
              height: 40.h,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: ColorUtils.COLOR_GRAY_AAAAAA[12],
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.h, horizontal: 12.w),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.r)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                  hintText: 'input_order_code'.tr,
                  hintStyle: TextStyleUtils.sizeText15Weight400().copyWith(color: ColorUtils.COLOR_GRAY_AAAAAA),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
                style: TextStyleUtils.sizeText15Weight400().copyWith(color: ColorUtils.COLOR_GRAY_363636),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
               SizedBox(
              
                height: 50,
                child: TextField(
                
                  cursorHeight: 25,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      filled: true,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Search Here...'),
                ),
              )
```